# Entry Descriptor Syntax Invalid Configuration

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-4

So i'm trying to configure my webpack config to use the entry descriptor syntax as described [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/).

This is an example of my config:

```
    entry: {
      shared: [
        'react',
        'prop-types',
        'lodash',
        'moment',
        './src/utils/polyfills.js',
    ],
    index: { import: './src/index.js', dependOn: 'shared' },
  }
```

However, when I run my build I'm constantly seeing errors saying this syntax doesn't match their API.

Start Command: "dev": "webpack --watch --config webpack.client.js"

Error

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry['index'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['index'] should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
      -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings
    * configuration.entry['index'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string]
      -> All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
    * configuration.entry['index'] should be one of these:
      non-empty string | [non-empty string]
      -> An entry point with name
```

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Entry descriptors are a feature introduced in Webpack v5 which is currently in [beta](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta.14). This syntax is not available in Webpack v4. The [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/) seems to have switched to v5 already, documentation for v4 can be found [here](https://v4.webpack.js.org/).